# How do I show only certain actors can perform a task in a use case diagram?

Tags: uml, diagram, use-case, use-case-diagram

I am working on a use case diagram for a library system. I have student and teacher actors. The students can only borrow certain books and the teachers can borrow all books. What is the best way to illustrate this?

I currently have "staff" and "student" actors that can "search catalog" but I am unsure on how to then go on to show books each different actor is allowed to borrow.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just attach a constraint telling who can do what,

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @qwerty_so on this one, it's the simplest solution available. If you want to complicate things, you can create abstract use case `Borrow a book` and specialize it into two use cases `Borrow any book` and `Borrow ??? book`. Replace ??? with proper adjective. Associate use case `Borrow any book` with `Teacher` actor and use case `Borrow ??? book` with `Student` actor.

When writing use cases, I tend to use use case specialization when a condition (in this case actor being the `Student`) leads to more significant changes than wording of one use case step. One example of such change might be the need to write a failure scenario called `User chooses inaccessible book` that is only relevant for `Borrow ??? book` use case.